Formatting: Date-Dependent and Rank (Another Cell) JSON Formatting
I need to apply a hierarchy of styles to a cell depending on 1) values in another field, then 2) values in the current field. I need to gray out a cell if it meets certain criteria, and apply date-dependent formatting if certain other criteria are met.
I'll try to illustrate:
Supervisor column = yes: grayed out
Supervisor column = no: date-dependent formatting applied
AND
Rank column = 1, 2, or 3: grayed out
Rank column = 4: date-dependent formatting applied
The date formatting I'm using is below. It's working well for the columns that don't have variables from other cells involved. I need to know how/where in the JSON code to insert the above conditional formatting so only the relevant cells within the column have the date formatting applied.
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(@currentField <= (@now - (86400000 *365)), 'red', if((@currentField <=  (@now - (86400000 *304)) &&  @currentField >= (@now - (86400000 *364))), 'yellow', 'green'))",
    "font-size": "12px",
    "font-weight": "bold",
    "justify-content": "center",
    "color": "=if((@currentField <=  (@now - (86400000 *304))) &&  (@currentField >= (@now - (86400000 *364))), 'black', 'white')"
  }
}


In your condition, can I say like: If (supervisor=no OR rank=4) DateField grayed out? Or both would be with AND like if (supervisor=no AND rank=4) DateField grayed out?

Supervisor=no supersedes everything, regardless of rank.

Please review my answer  and let me know if this works for you.

As I understood the requirements, the following might work.
Please note that in my example, [Supervisor] and [Rank] columns are Choice type.
My interpretation:
If([Supervisor] is "Yes" AND [Rank] in (1, 2, or 3)) Gray out the Date Column
else format the Date Column based on the already-implemented logic
{ "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json", 

"elmType": "div", "txtContent": "@currentField",
"style": { "background-color": "=if( ([$Supervisor]=='Yes' && [$Rank]!='4'), 'gray',if(@currentField <= (@now - (86400000 *365)), 'red', if((@currentField <= (@now - (86400000 *304)) && @currentField >= (@now - (86400000 *364))), 'yellow', 'green')))",
 "font-size": "12px",
 "font-weight": "bold", 
 "justify-content": "center",
 "color": "=if((@currentField <=  (@now - (86400000 *304))) &&  (@currentField >= (@now - (86400000 *364))) && ([$Supervisor]=='No' || [$Rank]=='4'), 'black', 'white')"
       }  
 }





That does it! Thank you!
